# Prove that semi-simple part and nilpotent part of $T$ commutes with $T$ if $T$ commutes with $A$.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

For $S-N$ Decomposition of a linear operator $T$ i.e $T=S+N$(Unique Expression) where $S$ is a semi-simple opearator and $N$ is a nilpotent operator and $SN=NS$ then prove that semi-simple part and nilpotent part of $T$ commutes with $A$ if $T$ commutes with $A$, where $A$ is a linear operator.

Comment: What is $A$?$~$

Comment: I have edited it, sorry..